# Como remover uma linha em arquivo txt no python

Tags: python, hash

Boa noite, estou tendo problemas ao remover uma linha de um arquivo txt, a função deleta do código é responsavel por remover um usuário, no entanto ao tentar remover o arquivo todo é excluido.

```
def deleta():

    usuario = input("\nUsuário: ") + "\n"
    senha = input("Senha: ")
    confirma = input("Confirma a exclusão de "+usuario+"? \ns/n: ")
    confirma.lower()

    if confirma == 's' or 'sim':
        with open("users.txt", 'r') as users:
            loginAndPass = users.readlines()
            # Proucura pelo login
            if usuario in loginAndPass:
                posi = loginAndPass.index(usuario)
                # autentica
                if posi % 2 != 0:
                    if testSHA512(senha, loginAndPass[int(posi) + 1].replace('\n', '')):
                        users = open("users.txt", 'w')
                        while posi in loginAndPass:
                            loginAndPass.remove(posi)
                            users.writelines(loginAndPass)
                            users.close()
                        print("\nUsuario removido\n")
                    else:
                        print("\nUsuário ou Senha inválidos\n")
                else:
                    print("\nUsuário ou Senha inválidos\n")
            else:
                print("\nUsuário ou Senha inválidos\n")
    elif confirma == 'n' or 'nao':
        print("passou")
    else:
        print("Opção inválida\nPrograma finalizado!")
```

Comment: A linha `confirma.lower()` é inútil, pois [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) retorna uma cópia da string convertida para _lowercase_ e você não está salvando o resultado. O que você quer fazer parece ser `confirma = confirma.lower()`. E a linha `if confirma == 's' or 'sim':` não faz o que você pensa que faz, o correto seria `if confirma == 's' or confirma == 'sim':` ou ainda `if confirma in ('s', 'sim'):`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, fiz as mudanças nescessarias.

Comment: Mais uma dica, você abriu o arquivo para leitura nesta linha: `open("users.txt", 'r')  as users` mas está tentando gravar em `users.writelines(loginAndPass)`

Answer (score 1):

Teu problema está nisso aqui `while posi in loginAndPass:`. Você apaga o arquivo em `users = open("users.txt", 'w')` e o código no `while` nunca vai ser executado, porque você esta procurando por um `int` em uma lista que só tem `strings`.

Se tua senha fica na próxima linha usa isso:

```
# remove o usuario
loginAndPass.pop(posi)
# remove a senha
loginAndPass.pop(posi)
users = open("users.txt", 'w')
users.writelines(loginAndPass)
users.close()
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, resolvi com sua dica, desculpe pela trivialidade, más sou novo no python e não conheço muitas funçẽs, agora é resolver o problema de salgar a senha.